# How get hash for user transaction?

Tags: solidity, remix, metamask, etherscan, ethers.js

Help me please .
if we will using :
await provider.getTransaction('0xeed4fadf09e9560f01056f240f86b515dce717087a42c7266bf659edef555861')  ---> in this case i will have result for only this hash .

But i need to get hash with dynamic users for any transactions like :
const tx = provider.getTransaction(anyTransactionHash) ;

so How can get anyTransactionHash ?
Thanks

Comment: Hello. I do not understand what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably what you want is to monitor pending transactions? If that's the case, you need to connect to a node via websocket and subscribe to the "PendingTransactions". Something like this:

```
var Web3 = require('web3')

const main = async () => {
  // reconnect options
  const options = {
    reconnect: {
      auto: true,
      delay: 2000,
      maxAttempts: 3,
      onTimeout: false,
    },
  }
  const web3 = new Web3(
    new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://your-node-endpoint/12345',
      options
    )
  )

  // subscribe to pendingTransactions events
  web3.eth
    .subscribe('pendingTransactions', async (error, result) => {
      if (error) console.log('error', error)
    })
    .on('data', async (trxId) => {
      // receives the transaction id
      console.log('TRX ID >> ', trxId)
      // query all transaction details using its id
      const trxDetails = await web3.eth.getTransaction(trxId)
      console.log(`TRX ${trxId} DETAILS >> `, trxDetails)
    })
}

main()
```